# jQuery toggle expand and collapse

Tags: jquery, toggle

I created 3 boxes in one row and want to use toggle for them, by default clicking on each one some content will appear below. Now I want to have close button on each content and Plus by click on other boxes to expand, the remain expanded contents should be collapsed.

I'm using uikit,

here is the link you can see: http://hamliran.com/index.php/test-page

When you click on project 1 the content will appear, by clicking on project 2 the target content should be expand and first content should be close.

Tnx

Comment: Please show us what you have and where you have problems with your code.

Comment: We ask you to share your code because we don't like going to your site and use inspect element.. it would be better if you copied your spesific HTML, CSS and jQuery so we can deal with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2ULx/29/)..

```
$("div.result").each(function(){
   $(this).slideToggle(0);//close all target content
});
$("div.name").click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        //if it's currently shown, close it
        $("div"+$(this).text()).slideToggle(0);
    }else{
        $("div.name").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                //close any opened target content
                $("#"+$(this).text()).slideToggle(0);
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        });
        //open the new selected one
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#"+$(this).text()).slideToggle(100);
    }

})
```

Comment: Is it possible that all of them have close button also?